# Redirection after last iteration in a loop of asynchronous mongodb updates

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm building an app with Node/Express/Mongodb/Mongoskin

I have this code to update a collection of documents:

```
db.collection('invoices').find().toArray(function(err, dbDocs) {
  if (err) throw err; 

  // Change one, none or several fields named 'paid' in the fetched invoices array
  ...

  // Loop trough the changed dbDocs and use it to update the database.
  for (var i = 0, j = dbDocs.length; i < j; i += 1) { 
    db.collection('invoices').update({_id:dbDocs[i]._id}, {$set:{ paid: dbDocs[i].paid }}, function(err, result) {
      if (err) throw err; 

      // Trigger a redirect after the last iteration.
      if (!err && (i === dbDocs.length - 1)) { 
        console.log('"i" is right now: ', i);
        res.redirect('/superadmin/fakturor');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

This will not work, because the update() function is having a callback, and when that callback finally fires the for-loop is already finished, which means that redirect will be called four times. 
I want the redirect to be called ONCE, that is after the last iteration AND there is no errors.

How do I rewrite this code to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First mind `i = dbDocs.length` it should be: `i == dbDocs.length-1`

Now, try this:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < dbDocs.length; i += 1) {
    (function (i) {
        db.collection('invoices').update({ _id: dbDocs[i]._id }, { $set: { paid: dbDocs[i].paid } }, function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;

            // Trigger a redirect after the last iteration.
            if (!err && (i == dbDocs.length-1)) {
                console.log('i: ', i);
                res.redirect('/superadmin/fakturor');
            }
        });
    })(i)
}
}
```

Comment: This code works!!
I recognize this pattern of using functions, but I'm not quite sure HOW it works. Could you please explain this in words, and do you know if this pattern has a "name"?

Comment: Basically the problem is that, when the callback function is being called the for loop has finished already so the `i` variable equals `dbDocs.length`. This trick just creates an anonymous function and calls it when the `i` variable has appropriate value. Calling the function copies the value of `i` -- so it is like taking a snapshot of `i`. Now this is very frequent issue in JS, you can read more about it. I dunno a name, but would call it something like *callback with loop variable*.

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical use case of the [`async` library](https://github.com/caolan/async), from which you can use some helper functions to deal with your concurrency issues.

You can use [`async.each(arr, iterator, callback)`](https://github.com/caolan/async#each), which will call `iterator()` on each member of the array. When all iterators are done, it calls the `callback` function.

```
var async = require('async');

var updateDoc = function (elem, cb) {
  db.collection('invoices').update({_id:elem._id}, {$set:{ paid: elem.paid }}, cb);
}

var done = function (err) {
  if (err)
    return console.error(err.message);
  res.redirect('/superadmin/fakturor');
}

async.each(dbDocs, updateDoc, done);
```